# MySQL Table for comments

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, comments

I made a link to a page in a document named "find.php" and made `$id` equal to the id of an article. When you click on it, the url looks like `find.php?id=w/e`. I want to be able to post comments on the page. For instance if I wanted to post a comment on `find.php?id=40`, how would I display the comments? By the way, there's a  table for the articles and a table for the comments.

For reference, I set up my comments table as

```
com_id int (11)
title text
user varchar (255)
msg text
```

Would I need a foreign key also?

Answer (score 2):

tableArticle:

```
id (int) PK
...
...
```

tableComment:

```
com_id (int) PK
article_id (int) FK to tableArticle on id
comment (varchar(255))
```

To display comments:

Your SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableComment WHERE article_id = w\e id
```

Your code (note that I can't test the syntax now):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
     echo $row[1];
}
```

Comment: I'm still not sure of you question, is that all you need?

Comment: i think so because find.php?id=article id and when someone wants to post a comment, they post it alongside the article because article id is a fk to the table where the articles are

Comment: my question was how would i display those comments

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need a foreign key from the comments table to the articles table, so you can reference which article each comment is for.